# Shell Script : command not found error

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/bash

calc()
{
        n1=$1
        op=$2
        n2=$3
        ans=0

        if [ $# -eq 3 ]
                then
                $ans=$(expr $n1 $op $n2);
                echo "$n1 $op $n2 = $ans"
                return $ans
        else
                echo "Needs 3 parameters!"
        fi

        return;

}
```

I googled alot but I still can not find the error in my code, I know this is a very simple code but please help me I'm totally new and trying to self study.

The error I get is

```
line 12: 0=11: command not found
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) helpfully points out that you shouldn't use `$` on the left-hand side of an assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is coming the '$ans' on this line

```
 $ans=$(expr $n1 $op $n2);
```

Should be

```
ans=$(expr $n1 $op $n2);
```

The '$' is evaluating the variable 'ans', as a result instead of assigning the result to your variable 'ans', it is trying to assign the result to '0'.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

calc()
{
        n1=$1
        op=$2
        n2=$3
        ans=0

        if [ $# -eq 3 ]
                then
                ans=$(expr $n1 $op $n2)
                echo "$n1 $op $n2 = $ans"
                return $ans
        else
                echo "Needs 3 parameters!"
        fi

        return

}

calc 6 + 5
```

Figured out! :)